# I have Question about class overriding in C++

Tags: c++

When I study about `override` keyword, I found some strange thing like below code.

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T> 
class A
{
    public: 
        virtual void some_function(const T a)
        {
            std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Base"<<std::endl;
        }
};
class Derived : public A<int*>
{
    public:
        virtual void some_function(const int* a)
        {
            std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Derived"<<std::endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    A<int*>* p = new Derived;
    p->some_function(nullptr);

    delete p;
}
```

When I first saw that code, I expected **"Derived"** to be called.
But above code print result like below.

```
void A<T>::some_function(T) [with T = int*]

Base
```

But when I removed `const` keyword in the `some_function` that placed in `Derived` class,

```
class Derived : public A<int*>
{
    public:
        virtual void some_function(int* a)
        {
            std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Derived"<<std::endl;
        }
};
```

It print **"Derived"**.
Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: How would you analyze the code if it was written as `T const a` and `int* const a`? Does it still look the same? This why it is said that leading const is mileading, you know.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica,  It print "Dervied". 
Plus you mean the "const T a" is wrong usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function prototypes are not the same. For `T=int*` `const T a`: `a` is a `const` pointer to an `int`, while `const int *a` is a pointer to an `const int`. For one the pointer is `const`, for the other the `int` is `const`.

`int * const a` would be the same as `const T a`, or you can make `T=const int*`.

https://godbolt.org/z/WEaEoGh58

Also important to note: When you derive from a `class` you must declare a `virtual` destructor.

A hint: when you use the keyword `override` on the derived function, you will get an error that you are not overriding the function: https://godbolt.org/z/o87GMrhsd

Comment: Thank you really helpful information!

Answer (score 1):

At

```
const T a
```

const qualifier is interpreted as top-level cv-qualifier for T, so it is processed

```
T const a
```

thus if int* is set to T, parameter type becomes

```
int* const a
```

So, your Derived's function signature (it is called second level const qualifier)

```
const int* a
```

is different from Base's one. As a result, your Derived virtual function is not called.

In addition, C++ has the rule of "ignore top-level cv-qualifier from function signature". So, your Base's signature

```
int* const
```

and if you give the type of

```
int*
```

into Derived's signature, these two types signature are interpreted to be equivalent. As a result, your Derived virtual function is called correctly.

---

The following is a back-ground for your help. The type of

```
T*
```

has two component T and pointer and then

```
T* const
```

is called top-level cv-qualifier which is applied to *, and then

```
T const *
```

is called second level cv-qualifier which is applied to T (equal to const T*). C++ ignore top-level cv-qualifier from signature. On the other hand, second level qualifier is included to signature. Therefore for example,

```
void f(int*) {}
void f(int* const){}
```

is failed to compile because of same signature by top-level cv-qualifier ignoring. In contrast,

```
void f(int*) {}
void f(int const * ){}
```

is compiled successfully by the difference of second level cv-qualifiers.

This is important to understand the behavior of virtual function calls. The reason is that the signature of derived virtual function and base's one must be identical to call it correctly.

Comment: Thank you!
It is useful infromation Thanks!